# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01858

```
create table fb_post (    
post_id int primary key,    
post_author varchar(5),    
post_wall_id varchar(5),    
post_date date,    
post_location varchar(50),    
foreign key (post_author) references fb_user(fb_id),    
foreign key (post_wall_id) references fb_wall(wall_id));

insert into fb_post
values(1201,'F2','W6',to_date('Oct-02-07 09:11:17','mon-dd-yy hh24:mi:ss'),'Gonzales, LA, United States');

insert into fb_post
values(1202,'F3','W8'   ,to_date('Oct-02-07 01:31:39','mon-dd-yy hh24:mi:ss'),'Gonzales, LA, United States');

insert into fb_post
values(1203,'F12','W14',to_date(' Oct-02-07 09:10:54, 'mon-dd-yy hh24:mi:ss'),'Pasadena,LA,United States');
```

The first and third rows are being created but the second one fails saying,

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `'` after `09:10:54`:

```
insert into fb_post
values(1203,'F12','W14',to_date(' Oct-02-07 09:10:54', 'mon-dd-yy hh24:mi:ss'),'Pasadena,LA,United States');
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, i changed that but still it returns same error.

Comment: Try removing the space in `' Oct`

Comment: That too did not work, only the first row and third are created the second row fails.

Comment: @kiran6 It should work with just the first fix (the missing `'`). Are you sure you made that change? If so, are you sure you aren't actually having a problem with code that you haven't posted here?

Comment: @EdCottrell the whole code works fine in SQl Fiddle but when i run the whole thing in my college sql data base only the first and the third rows are created and all the rest returns errors. The whole code compiled here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca406/1

Comment: Your SQLFiddle code doesn't match what's in your question. Please post the definitions and data for fb_user and fb_wall.

Comment: This is for fb_user

create table fb_user(

fb_id varchar(5) primary key,

fb_email varchar(30) not null,

fb_fname varchar(15) not null,

fb_lname varchar(15) not null,
fb_dob date not null,

fb_place varchar(50) not null,
fb_gender varchar(4) not null);

Comment: This is for fb_wall
create table fb_wall (
wall_id varchar(5) primary key,
wall_fb_id varchar(5) not null,
wall_view varchar(5) not null,
foreign key (wall_fb_id) references fb_user(fb_id));

Comment: @kiran6 - "all the rest return errors" - they all get ORA-01858, even for the second insert with the quote fixed? Or different errors now, like a constraint violation maybe?